# What is the way to give bitter medicine to a 2 year old child?

Tags: toddler, medicine

Child is 2 years and 1 month old.

No, I will not close her nose to make her open her mouth.

What are the other non torturous ways to give bitter medicine to the child?

Comment: @stephie it is not a duplicate because there is a hell lot of difference between a 2 year old and a 4 year old. A 2 year old kid cannot be explained the logics.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius I actually don't see anything in the accepted answer to the linked duplicate that wouldn't work for a two year old.  That's pretty much how we handle my two year old, anyway.

Comment: I'm split on closing it as a duplicate, because of the age difference. I've now supplied two different answers, because I do think how I would handle it for a 2-year-old vs a 4-year-old is different. (Under the presumption that a 4-year-old is likely more accustomed to medicine in general).